# Variable in function identify a dictionary name

Tags: python, dictionary

I’ve two dictionaries

```
dictionary_1 = {
    "key 1":"value 1.d1",
    "key 2":"value 2.d1",
    "key 3":"value 3.d1",
}

dictionary_2 = {
    "key 1":"value 1.d2",
    "key 2":"value 2.d2",
    "key 3":"value 3.d2",
}
```

And I want to create a function where I can print some value giving in the body of the function:

```
def print_keys(n):
    request = "dictionary_"
    for i in range(n)[1:]:
        request = "dictionary_"+str(i)
        print(request["key 3"])
```

But when I try to use the function the interpreter throws me an error because the name of the dictionary in the function is an string so, it is not possible to find. There is a way to cast the string in order to find the key/value pair?

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-d31d90b742bc> in <module>()

----> 1 print_keys(3)

<ipython-input-31-6f658f8afacf> in print_keys(n)
      3     for i in range(n)[1:]:
      4         request = "dictionary_"+str(i)
----> 5         print(request["key 3"])

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Beside that i’m asking if there is a more efficient way to work this kind of problems.

Comment: You can't refer to a variable using a string containing the variable name. You'd need to use `eval` to get the variable, but that's evil. Why not just pass the dicts to `print_keys`?

Comment: But, for example. I've 40 dictionary. How can I make a function that, taking a number by parameter print the value for the key 3 for each dict?

Comment: Maybe use a list?

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/Tracebacks. Just copy the Traceback and paste it as text then format it as code. - [You should not post code as an image because:...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755)

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is use a string of the name `'dictionary_1'` to reference a variable `dictionary_1`. This won't work.

It can be achieved using the `eval` function. Like so

```
def print_keys(n):
    request = "dictionary_"
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        request = eval("dictionary_"+str(i))
        print(request["key 3"])
```

It converts the string to the variable, if the variable exists.

This is not a nice way to operate.`eval` is a potential security loophole and often it necessity is a sign of poor design. In this case there is coupling between the `print_keys` function and the names of some global `dict`s elsewhere in your code.

Instead I suggest the best way would be to pass a list of `dict`s to be processed and

```
def print_keys2(dl, key):
    for dct in dl:
        print(dct[key])
```

used like

```
print_keys2([dictionary_1, dictionary_2], 'key 3')
```

Note that you don't need to have any fragile naming scheme for your dict variables. You can call them whatever you want. It leaves you free to give them meaningful names.